# Ruby on Rails: Devise login / sign up in modal not working on mobile phones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So I used the devise gem and it worked perfectly. I had a login page and a signup page. In order to improve the UX, I turned it into a modal. What did I do?

I basically cut and pasted the view into a modal tag on my navbar. and left it at that. It worked perfectly on desktop, but on mobile it takes about 2 min before the page updates and signs me in. Why is that?

I looked around stack overflow and actually it seems like just copying and pasting the view isnt the right way to do... but why the hell does it work so well on Desktop?

I am attaching my modal code here. Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Thanks for the help :)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="LoginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="loginmodal-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <h2 class="text-center text-center-modal">Log in</h2>

                <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder:"Email", class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder:"Password", class: "form-control"  %>
                  </div>


                  <div>
                     <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
                         <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> Remember Me
                     <% end %>
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <%= link_to "Forgot Password", new_user_password_path%>
                    </span>
                 </div>

                    <br/><br/>

                  <div class="actions">
                    <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block" %>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
                <hr/>
                <%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path, class: "btn btn-facebook btn-block" %>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```